# Php query to mysql database not giving desired results

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a database table with months, the number value for the months and years. **eg. June, 6, 2020**.

I have a select drop-down that dynamically populates based on the data from the table.

The idea is, if the current month is June, the select dropdown should only be populated with the months of June to December.

The issue I am having, which I don't undestand, is that on the page when I run the query, the drop down is only being populated with May to September. Whereas if I run the same query directly on the table in the database, I get the desired results.

The query below:

```
    $yvalue = $_POST['years']; //assume this to be "2020";
    $curyear = date('Y');
    $curmonth = date('n'); // Lets also assume this to be "5";

    if ($yvalue==$curyear) {

    $query = "SELECT calmonthsID, months, value, years from calmonths WHERE years=? AND value>=? ORDER BY calmonthsID ASC";
    $stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $yvalue, $curmonth);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($calmonthsID, $months, $value, $years);

    }else{
    $query = "SELECT calmonthsID, months, value, years from calmonths WHERE years=? ORDER BY calmonthsID ASC";
    $stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $yvalue);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($calmonthsID, $months, $value, $years);
    }

    echo "<option>- Select Month -</option>";   

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$months.'</option>'; 
    } $stmt->close();
```

When the above query runs on the page, the drop down is populated with months May to September. Omitting October to December.

When I assumed `$curmonth = date('n');` to be `10` I get the drop down populated with months February to December. Omitting January.

Again When I assumed `$curmonth = date('n');` to be `11` I get the drop down populated with months February to December. Omitting January and October.

And when I assumed `12`, January, October  and November were missing.

But running all these queries directly in the database gave the desired results. So I am puzzled as to what is wrong or what is happening when running the queries in Php.

This is the database data:

```
calmonthsID  months      value     years
1            January      1        2020
2            Febuary      2        2020
3            March        3        2020
4            April        4        2020
5            May          5        2020
6            June         6        2020
7            July         7        2020
8            August       8        2020
9            September    9        2020
10           October      10       2020
11           November     11       2020
12           December     12       2020
13           January      1        2021
....
```

Comment: I think this is a typo date('n'); instead use date('m');

Comment: @Hardood why? `m` just adds leading zero to the output. MySQL won't care about that.

Comment: Michael, I think this will be hard to solve without you showing us the database data. Please update your post with a table of sample data, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, got it @ADyson, i always use it with intval(date('m')); :)

Comment: @Hardood ah well turning it back into an integer (instead of a string which `date` outputs) will strip the leading zero again...observe: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0209a3fc3f92cf18764fb0d6882dc4c05095458

Comment: @ADyson I have included the database data

Comment: Data type of the fields years and value are int in your table, right?

Comment: Ok thanks. By any chance is `value` a `varchar` field in your database? It needs to be `int`.

Comment: @Hardood No. only calmonthsID has a datatype of int. The others are varchar.

Comment: I suggest you change the data type of value to int and test again.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @ADyson and @Hardood. The data type was the issue. After changing the `value` to `int` its working as desired now.

Comment: @MichaelAgbogidi that's great. See my answer below for a fuller explanation, and please mark it as "accepted" if you're happy with it. Thanks.

Comment: To think that that was what got me brainstorming for a few hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've defined the `value` column in your database as `varchar` instead of `int`. It needs to be `int`, otherwise MySQL will do a string comparison for the `>=` test in your query instead of a numeric comparison.

A string comparison does a character-by-character comparison of the two values, with the result that, for example `5` is seen as greater than `10` because it actually compares the `5` with the `1` first.

It's important that you assign the correct data type to your columns - if you want something to be treated as a number and be able to do maths on it, then you must declare it as a numeric field.

You can see the difference in the results with the two different data types here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=def28599d8180932de25342ea6647782

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand better now what was going on.